# Rockshox Pike Scratch

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, repair, fork, shocks

I have a rockshox pike with scratches on the fork stanchion. I would like to know if there was anything I can do without buying a new one. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't leak oil or anything, you always have the option of just leaving it as is. "If it ain't broke don't fix it." Otherwise, clear nail polish is an option. You'll want to extremely carefully sand or file the rough edges off.

You can also buy just the upper half of the fork. You don't need to replace the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (value and quality) is to replace the Crown Steerer Unit (CSU).

There are other fixes such as nail polish but you always run the risk of tearing the seals.

The work isn’t much difference to a full fork service.

You can get the part number here: https://www.servicearchive.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/rockshox_spc_-_rev_f_0.pdf

You will also need a new service pack, fluids and star nut.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Do you think the current scratch compromises anything for which replacement is absolutely necessary?

Comment: The lower legs are relatively dry in most forks these days. The biggest risks would be contaminants (water and dirt) getting in below the seals and impacting how smoothly the forks work and increased wear on the stanchion over time. I don't think you need to rush out and replace it, there's little risk of catastrophic failure and the air spring is sealed from the rest of the lower leg.